# cal-heatmap displaying values

Tags: json, cal-heatmap

Hopefully, this is not a very difficult problem.
Here's where the problem lies:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cal = new CalHeatMap();
cal.init({
itemSelector: "#subDomainTextFormat-b",
start: new Date(2017, 3), // April, 1st 2017
data: "http://localhost/2017OS.json",
domain: "month",
subDomain: "x_day",
cellSize: 20,
range: 6,
displayLegend: false,   
subDomainTextFormat: function(date ,value) {
    return value;
}
});
</script>
```

The json is properly formatted and the dates in the initial display of the calendar are correct. I am not seeing the values displayed when I apply the above code. For reference, the json looks like this:

```
    {
  "1491004800":40,
  "1491091200":56,
  "1491177600":52,
  "1491264000":53,
  "1491350400":58,
  "1491436800":48,
  "1491523200":44,
  "1491609600":57,
  "1491696000":62,
  "1491782400":68,
  "1491868800":73,
  "1491955200":61
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Hi Micki Thanks! My json actually looks like your proposed edit. I probably made a mistake in copying it into the editor. This seems like it should be fairly easy, but for me it is not :-(

Comment: Even with the correct format, I am unable to display the values

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of Cal-Heatmap in your application
from https://github.com/wa0x6e/cal-heatmap/archive/master.zip
i think u use 3.3.10 version , u shoud use v3.6.2 version.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31352177)